# Clear search box on the click of a little "x" inside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a search form for a tumblr theme. I'm wondering if there's any simple JavaScript, CSS, or jQuery solution that when a little tiny "x" image **inside** the textbox is clicked, it clears the form? An example of this is on apple.com. Here's the search code I'm working with:

```
<form id="search" action="/search">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="q"  placeholder="Search&hellip;" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: clears the form values or clears just the text input in which the image is positioned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not INSIDE actually...

Try this:

```
<span class="search"><img src=lookup><input type=text ><span>x</span></span>
```

with the style:

```
span.search 
  {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:0.5em; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.5em;    
  }
span.search > input 
  {
    background: none;
    border: none;
  }
```

Comment: elegant solution with border-radius, not requiring an image, however, IE <9 will render a square instead (still useable), also, gotta set height and width to 1em, and experiment with the fonts that are best suited to render that (X)

Comment: Instead of X multiplication sign can be used: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d7/index.htm

Answer (score 6):

To expand on kingjv's solution, this is a simple plugin:
http://jsfiddle.net/PvFSF/

```
(function ($, undefined) {  
    $.fn.clearable = function () {  
        var $this = this;  
        $this.wrap('<div class="clear-holder" />');  
        var helper = $('<span class="clear-helper">x</span>');  
        $this.parent().append(helper);  
        helper.click(function(){  
            $this.val("");  
        });  
    };  
})(jQuery);
```

$("#myInput").clearable();

Comment: [Added some code](http://jsfiddle.net/PvFSF/155/) to show/hide the X depending on if text exists or not. Thanks for this, @Kroehre.

Answer (score 4):

It's only a css trick. If you see apple.com, what they're doing is to put the delete image after the text, but it seems to be inside.
Here you have the code to accomplish this effect:

```
<style>
  #searchContainer{
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    display: inline;
  }
  #q{
     border: none;
  }
</style>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#clear").click(function(){
        $("#q").val(""); //Clear the text input
     });
  });
</script>
<form id="search" action="/search">
    <p>         
        <div id="searchContainer">
          <input type="text" name="q" id="q" />
          <span id="clear">x</span> <!-- You can use an image here instead -->
        </div>
    </p>
</form>
```

It's tested & running :)
Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of Apple's site you'll see their search textbox is really a div, a textbox, then another div. It's these outer divs that hold the things like the x to clear it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nByBB/

probably want to make it a bit nicer of course but it illustrates the idea.

Answer (score 0):

using css give your input field right padding of, let's say 20px. Then make an image of (X) [and let's say your image has width of 20px and is called clear.png], include `<img class="clearingImage" src="/imagepath/clear.png" style="position:relative;left:-20px;" />` right after your  tag and then in your javascript block you say

```
$('img.clearingImage').click(function () {
   $(this).prev().val('');
});
```

keeping in mind that the image is positioned on the same line right after the input tag

Comment: also, check out c-smile's image-less solution below, can be used same way

Comment: right padding in input field will allow the image to appear within the bounds of the text box but text will not flow underneath it